# nss-3.14.1-3.fc16.src.rpm build fails with error: test suite returned failure(s)

Tags: mozilla, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, nss

I am trying to build nss-3.14.1-3.fc16.src.rpm on my fedora-16 with below command:

rpmbuild -ba nss.spec

and ending up with below error:

---

Tests summary:

Passed:             6398

Failed:             9

Failed with core:   0

Unknown status:     0

cd ../../../../

killall selfserv_9962

selfserv_9962: no process found

:

grep -c FAILED ./mozilla/tests_results/security/localhost.1/output.log

TEST_FAILURES=9

error: test suite returned failure(s)

'[' 9 -ne 0 ']'

echo 'error: test suite returned failure(s)'

exit 1

RPM build errors:

error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.G5KTZ1 (%check)

Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.G5KTZ1 (%check)

Child return code was: 1

---

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here and what should be done to avoid these error?

Comment: Some of the built-in tests failed. Nothing in that output indicates why exactly unfortunately. If you can find the `./mozilla/tests_results/security/localhost.1/output.log` file it might tell you more.

Comment: Have you tried to build it by hand outside of `rpmbuild`?

Comment: I found an error in output.log file that is like problem with 'CERT CHAIN'.
There is problem with cert chain while verifying 'EE2CA0.der' cerficate and showing like 'chain is bad' and 'Peer's Certificate has been revoked'.

I am stuck at this point because I am not getting any exact solution for build this nss rpm successfully.So can anyone tell me what is wrong here and what should be done to avoid these error?